# What is a buffer write?

Tags: terminology, buffer

Can some help me understand what a buffer write is? I'm particularly interested in learning its function in the context database systems, MySQL say! Some of the following would be helpful:

1. What is the purpose of a buffer write
2. Are there any performance advantages
3. An example of a buffer write in a database application

I came across this term several times and I was unable to discern its meaning.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a computer with 100M of memory, running a database.  The database stores data in files, but also  keeps 50M of it in memory in buffers.  If there is a request for data (SELECT or INSERT), the request can be handled from buffers in memory, which is much faster that going all the way to disk.

Buffering request for access to information in a database's files is essentially caching requests for disk I/O.  If information is INSERT-ed then DELETEd within a very short period of time, writing to disk may be unnecessary.  Not writing (buffers) greatly increases performance.

If there as a request to INSERT 100M of data into the database, then all pending writes, (from buffers to disk), must be done. Then at least half the new data is written to disk.  Data has to be written because there isn't enough memory for the 100M new data plus 50M old data to all reside in memory.  This necessity to write some existing buffers to disk is a performance hit. Luckily it is only the buffers holding changed or new records that need to be written out(or flushed) to disk.  Those changed buffers are referred to as "dirty."

After the aforementioned INSERT of 100M, some 50M of the new data may temporarily be held in memory until it's most convenient to write--because not writing increases performance. A convenient time to write write changed records back to disk is when the system has been idled for a while.  Writing (buffer writes) when the system is idle doesn't lower performance.

Comment: Thanks Frayser, I appreciate the response. Is this something that databases do automatically, or you have to set it yourself? I imagine it would depend on the database, but as a general idea...

Comment: All major databases PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, Sysbase, MsSQL, etc have and manage a cache of buffers. It's not normally something one has configure; but depending on the database Vendor and table design, there are parameters than can tweaked.  These adjustments are usually done by a Database Administrator when there is some special need for it. For any given database the details for making such adjustments can be found in the "Tuning" portion of the manual. Here is a [link to the reference for tuning MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-parameters.html)